# yolov3 Metrics Output Interpretation

Tags: metrics, training-data, yolo

I'm training a yolov3 neural network (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/) to recognize objects in an image and was able to get some metrics out.

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to interpret the following metrics (i.e. definition of what these metrics measure).

1. Objectness
2. Classification.

[yoloV3 Training Metrics Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sER3O.jpg)

I'm assuming the val Objectness and val Classification are the scores for the validation set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. Anyways, hope this useful for somebody.

Objectness: measures how well the model is at identifying that an object exists in a proposed region of interest

Classification: measures how well the model is at labeling those objects by their corresponding associated class

Both are usually calculated by `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` as both are classification tasks